# Show that $f(x)$ is differentiable for real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Show that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and give the value of
>   $f'(x)$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R};$ justify any assertions you make.
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\cos(x^4),\quad
> > &x\not=0 \\ 0, &x=0\end{cases}. $$

How do I go about this?

Comment: Use the definition of the derivative (at the origin, elsewhere it's kinda clear). Observe that $-x^2\le f(x)\le x^2$, so the squeeze theorem bites.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

For $x\neq 0$ we can calculate directly $f'(x)$.

For $x=0$ let consider the definition

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\,x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\cos(x^4)$$